# Give directions or let users leave site?

Tags: hyperlinks, instructions

I am updating an instructions page which relies on some information that is in an online book of laws (which is hosted elsewhere).

Currently, users are instructed to find a specific section in the book and given a link to a page on our site with the law book in an iframe. This page is used for other things too, so I can't put instructions directly on that page and I can't make the iframe start on the section that I am working with. That makes me think I have two options:

- 1) Leave it the way it is so users have to read the note and then go
  to another page. It's good that they don't have to leave our site, but this seems like a bad UX.
- 2) Give users a link which takes them away from our site to the exact
  page in the online law book that they need. It's good that this would take them directly to the information they need, but the downside is that it could be disorienting or confusing to be taken off of our site.

How would you all handle this?

Comment: Why can't you link directly to the exact page within the iframe? Alternatively, is embedding the content within the page an option?

Comment: The iframe is the code of laws for a specific municipality so it's a general use page. The iframe has to start on the beginning page of that code because only a subset of users are going to the section I need to send them to.

I guess I could have my own iframe on my own page, but it is my understanding that this is bad practice (though I suppose one is already being used anyway).

Comment: I would go with option #2 then. This might be veering towards an "implementation answer" but you can use css or javascript to open the link in a new window. This would prevent users from leaving the site as well as having to scroll to the relevant content.

Comment: @WilliamAnderson Thanks! I agree that would help a little.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the book of law is for general use and hosted elsewhere. Does that resource allow you to perfectly pinpoint a section to refer?

I would suggest you could provide some sort of distilled information within your page. So most of the users will be content with knowing it. For the more curious ones, you could refer them to an external page with clearly indicating that they will be leaving your page.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwMCaw.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The icon is commonly used icon indicating that you are leaving the site and going somewhere else. You could always open it in a separate window/tab.